# Proof there aren't $p(x), q(x)$ polynomials such that $\arctan(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}, \forall x \in (0,+\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

I've tried this, by contradiction, supposing that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ exist $$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \arctan x =\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}= \frac{π}{2}$$.Then the degree of both $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are the same, let's say $n$. Now, I differentiate the expression and try to get to a contradiction in the degrees on $q^2(x)=(1+x^2)[p'(x)q(x)-p(x)q'(x)]$. The leader term of $[p'(x)q(x)-p(x)q'(x)]$ cancels, so its degree is less than $2n-1$.

I know that my proffessor did It that way, but When I try It, I dont know why i dont get the contradiction.

Can someone help me? Thankss

Comment: More generally you can show that any periodic function is transcendental and therefore its inverse is also transcendental. A fortiori $\arctan x$ is not a rational function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that there are polynomial functions $p$ and $q$ such that$$(\forall x\in(0,\infty)):\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=\arctan x.$$Then, for each $x>0$, $\left(\frac pq\right)'(x)=\arctan'x=\frac1{1+x^2}$. But if two rational function are equal on an interval, they are equal everywhere. So, for each real $x$,\begin{align}\arctan x&=\int_0^x\arctan'(x)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^x\left(\frac pq\right)'(x)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}.\end{align}
You have $\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan x=\frac\pi2$. So, the polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ would have to have the same degree. But then$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=\frac\pi2.$$However,$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\arctan(x)=-\frac\pi2.$$

Comment: Excuse me, why does $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=\frac{\pi}{2}$. I don't see the contradiction here

Comment: You don't see a contradiction between $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=\frac\pi2$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=-\frac\pi2$? Then I don't know what is it that you mean when by “contradiction”.

Comment: No, what I don't see is why $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Because if $p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$ and $q(x)=b_nx^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+b_0$, with $a_n,b_n\ne0$, then$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=\frac{a_n}{b_n}.$$So, the limit cannot be equal to $\frac\pi2$ at $\infty$ and equal to $-\frac\pi2$ at $-\infty$.

Comment: Ah, ok. Now I get it. One last thing, and sorry for my clumsiness. In your proof, you use $x\to-\infty$, so this proof doesn't prove it $\forall x\in(0,+\infty)$ but $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, or am I wrong?

Comment: No. You are right. I shall edit my answer.

Comment: It's done. ${}$

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.